# Как подписаться на 2 события одному элементу? Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

При событии @click мне необходимо вызвать 2 метода, как это можно сделать? Пытался сделать данными способами, не пашет

```
@click="fetchHandler, openModal"
@click="fetchHandler || openModal"
```

Если подписаться на 2 события сразу во vue нельзя, возможно будет лучшим решением вызвать один метод внутри другого? И если да, то, пожалуйста, подскажите как это сделать. Методы следующие:

```
fetchHandler () {
  this.SET_FOOTERFORMS({
    name: this.name,
    phone: this.phone
  })
  Promise.allSettled([
    this.fetchFooterForms()
  ]).then(() => {
    this.getProps()
  })
},

openModal () {
  this.isOpened = !this.isOpened
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создал метод, вызывающий 2 метода и вызвал его в @click

```
openSuccess () {
  this.fetchHandler()
  this.openModal()
}
```